# Push notification in Blackberry(Server Side) for PhoneGap App

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am developing a mobile app using phonegap for android, iphone and blackberry platforms and I need to put a push notification feature in my app, so that my server can poll my app and then put the notification if there is any new notification.

On browsing the net i found out that there are plugins for phonegap for both iphone and android which help in showing the notification.But did not find any useful resources for Blackberry.:(

I want to get a push notification in Blackberry using phonegap can some one help me in performing this or any links which explains this with html,js is really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap's main site says that the push notifications supported for iOs, Android and BlackBerry.  I would assume that you will be able to find the plugin from their main site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PhoneGap for Blackberry it will use the WebWorks API by Blackberry.  This has built in notification support that you can use.  The api can receive a push notification and then execute an action as described by the notification.

See the reference API docs here:

[Blackberry WebWorks HTML5 Notifications](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/notification.html)

Comment: Can you please give some code on how to do that and the bounty is all yours.